# golang, how to disable autoscape in templates

Tags: javascript, go, templates

I have a template which is included from several other templates. I am passing in some data, and I want to dynamically create some javascript in each page.

I have the following in each template

```
<canvas id="{{.Id}}"></canvas>

<script type='application/ld+json'>
    const {{ .Id }} = new Chart(document.getElementById({{.Id}}) 
    ...
```

I expect to create something like this

```
<canvas id="someName"></canvas>

<script type='application/ld+json'>
    const someName = new Chart(document.getElementById(someName) 
    ...
```

but instead, I get this

```
<canvas id="someName"></canvas>

<script type='application/ld+json'>
    const "someName" = new Chart(document.getElementById("someName") 
    ...
```

After looking this up, apparently golang makes an attempt to add characters to my string out on my-behalf when it detects the 'script' tag. Obviously the true context of what I am doing is not understood by this feature. Is there any way to get around this 'helper feature', or even better, a way to disable this completely?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/3f8o0PPBd9U

Comment: Hacking it via JavaScript is a workaround I wound up doing. basically

window['{{.Id}}'] = new Chart(